# Django 1.6 run stand alone script in Django Environment- No Success

Tags: python, django

I have a stand alone script that I need to run in the Django environment. It uses the Database Orm and such. When I try to run it, it starts off complaining `from .generators import thread_generator`. So, it's obvious it's not in the Django environment. I have googled and tried many things and still have had no success. Currently, I am trying the below to no success. I am not even sure if `bot_server.local` is correct or if it should be `bot_server.settings`. However, I am using `local.py` in settings. I can't run this as a command because for the use I have for it, I need to run it as a stand alone script. I need this to be permanent from with in the script rather than a shell environment hack that is temp.

```
from functools import wraps
import sys
import os
import datetime
import base64
import json
from django.db import connection
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from .generators import thread_generator
from .do_request import do_request
from .models import Employee, ThreadVault

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = "bot_server.local"
    sys.path.append("/home/git/bot_server/bot_server")
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback? And out of curiosity: in what use-case do you have to run a stand-alone script using the Django environment where you can't use a management command?

Answer (score 3):

To run standalone script you just need to write this code before you start your script. The problem in executing standalone script is **it can not find django environment** so to provide this we need to ***append setting file.***

```
//Start your code here

import os, sys
from os import path

proj_path = "project_path\project_name"

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")
sys.path.append(proj_path)
os.chdir(proj_path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

from app1.models import *
from app2.models import model_name
from app3.models import model_name1, model_name2

application = get_wsgi_application()

//Start your script from here
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is really simple...just paste what is in manage.py:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bot_server.settings.local")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
```

With all the posts I have read, I can not believe that this was not mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this answer is making simple

manage.py file as belows

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from settings.common import PROJECT_ROOT
import os
import sys


os.chdir(PROJECT_ROOT)
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "..")))

for i, arg in enumerate(sys.argv):
   if arg.startswith("--site"):
      os.environ["MEZZANINE_SITE_ID"] = arg.split("=")[1]
      sys.argv.pop(i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    settings_module = "settings.common"
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", settings_module)
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```